# Stability and Morse functions.

Tags: differential-topology

I'm studying differential topology, I know that there are many properties which are stable, but I don't know if to be a Morse function is a stable property. I think that it is not true, but I haven't found a counterexample.
Thanks!

Comment: Is your manifold compact?

Comment: Yes, thank you Ted.

Comment: Then stability holds. For me the easiest argument is that when $M$ is compact, maps $M\to Y$ that are transverse to any *closed* submanifold $Z\subset Y$ form a stable family. And $f\colon M\to\Bbb R$ is Morse if and only if $\text{grad}\, f$ is transverse to the zero section of $TM$.

Comment: there is a problem in Guillemin and pollack 1.7.18 that proves stability of Morse functions.